# How to copy values based on multiple checks and fill the values for other rows in same table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for framing the question in an improper way but the logic I would like to clarify below for my problem. Hope it will help in understanding my problem

If I have below table as a sample data:

```
+-----+-----------+------+
|  a  |     b     |  c   |
+-----+-----------+------+
| 100 | Apple     | NULL |
| 100 | Orange    | 1.05 |
| 101 | Apple     | NULL |
| 102 | Apple     | NULL |
| 102 | Dont care | NULL |
| 103 | Apple     | NULL |
| 103 | Dont care | NULL |
| 103 | Orange    | 1.01 |
+-----+-----------+------+
```

Now I want to fill value of column C where it is NULL for column B = Apple. The value will be taken from column B= Orange of same column A value.

And if for a given distinct value of column A, we have column B= Apple but don't have column B = Orange, then the value of column C (for the given distinct value of column A and column B= Apple) should be populated with value of column C (for next ascending distinct value of column A having column B= Orange).

So my output should then look like:

```
+-----+-----------+------+
|  a  |     b     |  c   |
+-----+-----------+------+
| 100 | Apple     | 1.05 |
| 100 | Orange    | 1.05 |
| 101 | Apple     | 1.01 |
| 102 | Apple     | 1.01 |
| 102 | Dont care | NULL |
| 103 | Apple     | 1.01 |
| 103 | Dont care | NULL |
| 103 | Orange    | 1.01 |
+-----+-----------+------+
```

Thanks

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: @vkp MS SQL. I am using SSMS 2014.

Comment: can you also clarify `if for a given column A we don't have column B = Orange, then the value for column C should be populated when next time we encounter column B= Orange` ?

Comment: Specifically, what does "when next time we encounter.." mean?  Remember that SQLServer tables have no order of their own, you have to explicitly define an order in a query if you want one.

Comment: @vkp I have updated the question in more explained manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `outer apply`.

```
select t1.a,t1.b
,case when t1.b='Apple' and t1.c is null then t2.new_c else c end as new_c
from tbl t1
outer apply (select top 1 c as new_c 
             from tbl t2 where t2.a>=t1.a and t2.b='Orange' 
             order by a) t2
```